# How can I beat “Prototype” in Aqueduct for iPhone?

Tags: ios, aqueduct

I've been stuck on this level for 4 days; it is the 26th puzzle in the 4th level. If someone has completed it, could you please post the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kevin, we edit-collided, feel free to rollback my changes.

Comment: All better now. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's my [solution.](http://www.gamewithme.net/Images/prototype.jpg)
Sorry for the blurry pic but you can make out what do.